# Table Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table that stores sent emails and it is ridiculously slow to select from.
The grid has custom paging but the actual SQL query is slow it is pointless.

There would have been data going back to 2012 but we have deleted everything pre 01/01/2016 and I rebuilt the indexes.

It takes between 1 min 30 and 2 minutes to return 200k rows. (Excluding the Email Content field because to be fair that could be a big html string).

Any ideas as it doesn't really make sense for it to be so slow 220k isn't much records....

Columns:

```
PK EmailID
EmailTO varchar200
EmailCC varchar200
Subject varchar500
Message varchar max
Data sent smalldatetime
EmailBCC varchar max
```

Query:

```
select EmailID, EmailTo, EmailCC, Subject, DateSent 
from dbo.OutgoingEmails
```

Time 1:38 for 200603 rows

**Execution plan :** 
[Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaFJE.png)

**Wait stats:** [image: Wait stats here]

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? What's the hardware etc.? Are there any indexes on the table? How much data does 200K records represent (the MAX columns could be huge)

Comment: about the product it is SQL 2014

Comment: What does the **actual** execution plan for this query look like?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Kuyt there is only one index on primary key, and about second question - max column is excluded from the select as I presented in the query above

Comment: you should collect the wait stats for the session executing the query. To see if it is predominately waiting on disc, network IO or something else

Answer (score 0):

Please run reorg and runstat on table and then try your query. you just rebuilded the indexes, why not rebuild the table pages after deleting bunch of data from table ?

REORG and RUNSTAT

```
REORGANIZE TABLE dbo.OutgoingEmails;

UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.OutgoingEmails;
```

Comment: reorg and update stats brought it down to 59 secs 
I have my question updated by an execution plan

Comment: great, you saved now 40 seconds from original posted time 1:38. Can you just do ```select count(*) from dbo.OutgoingEmails``` and post the time it took to display the count ?

Comment: There is no `REORGANIZE TABLE` in SQL Server. There is an index reorganize command but pointless running it if the indexes have just been rebuilt. Similarly rebuilding an index will update stats on it and these won't be useful for a full table scan with no WHERE clause anyway.. Any perf improvement will likely be as they  brought the pages into cache so the query didn't have to read them from disc

Comment: @MartinSmith  Artur: When an index is reorganized in SQL Server, statistics are not updated. both these articles from Microsoft is good read regarding REORGANIZE and UPDATE STATISTICS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: When an index is REBUILT they are updated. And they state they have rebuilt the indexes